# Need Edit PDF component which will work in objective c, java & asp.net

Tags: java, android, asp.net, objective-c

I want to Develop a Editable PDF application which can edit pdf in all way, & it should work on all platform such as Android Iphone..Please suggest a library which will work on asp.net, Iphone. Android (Objective c and java & dot net platform)

Any help will be appreciated much.

Thanks